# Como configurar subdomínio no microsoft azure

Tags: microsoft-azure, domínio

Estou criando uma aplicação no Azure. 
Já configurei o domínio para o endereço principal: (`beleza.vc`), e esta tudo ok.

Agora estou com dificuldades para configurar um subdomínio que irá para a pasta blog. Ex: (`beleza.vc/blog`). Mas preciso que seja `blog.beleza.vc`.

O domínio foi registrado no `namecheap.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer isso é bem simples, basta, no seu DNS, criar uma entrada `CNAME` com nome `blog` apontando para `beleza.vc/blog`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se tiver usando o [Azure DNS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/dns/) - pois vc pode registrar seu domínio no NameCheap e usar os *domain namespaces* do Azure - para gerenciar a hospedagem do seu domínio, basta clicar em "+ Record set" e adicionar a entrada assim:

- NAME: blog
- TYPE: CNAME
- TTL: 60
- VALUE: beleza.vc/blog

[image: Azure DNS Zone]

Se a gestão de domínio não estive no Azure e gostaria de experimenta, leia aqui como [delegar seu domínio ao Azure DNS](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/dns/dns-domain-delegation).

Comment: Thiago, pode mostrar por favor como transforma isso para blog.beleza.vc?

Comment: Vc tendo funcionando `beleza.com.br/blog`, basta no seu DNS, criar uma entrada `CNAME` com nome `blog` e com valor `beleza.com.br/blog`. Assim toda vez que aguém acessar `blog.beleza.com`, sua app irá entregar o conteúdo de `beleza.com.br/blog`.